# Положительные оценки

Tags: обсуждение

За собой заметил, что очень мало ставлю оценок в плюс. Просто, сложившаяся культура на ресурсе что ли такая. Не понятно. И решил взять свою главную страницу с вопросами за сегодня и подсчитать как оценены вопросы за сегодня. Статистика на быстрый взгляд только по вопросам без учета закрытых, удаленных и тех которые не отображаются у меня выглядит следующим образом

| Отрицательный рейтинг | рейтинг = 0 | больше 0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 64 | 12 |

Данный результат заставляет задуматься, почему вопросы так слабо оцениваются в положительную сторону. Возьмем с нулем рейтинга. На данные вопросы имеются ответы и ответы с положительным рейтингом. Но все равно рейтинг самих вопросов остается с нулем.

Какие ваши критерии чтобы положительно оценить вопрос?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNAJL.png

Comment: Кстати, главную не очень правильно считать, лучше вопосы.

Comment: Да, и я смотрю на время с момента регистрации. Это за почти 6,5 лет. Это примерно 23 голоса "за" в месяц.

Comment: Тьфу, профиль на мете посмотрел вместо обычного. Вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfTA6.png

Comment: Так вопросов заслуживающих плюс пишется очень мало, гораздо чаще пишут то что заслуживает минус... И предвидя возвышенные речи от "набигающих" в такие обсуждения "борцов со злобностью ruSO", сразу выскажу имху: такая статистика не должна как-то смущать оценивающих - она объективно показательна в плане общей оценки качества большинства вопросов, **и только**. В каждом случае оценки конкретного вопроса, имеет смысл руководствоваться именно его содержанием, а не какими-либо стат.соотношениями типа "сегодня я поставил N минусов, значит надо и плюсиков наставить во имя культуры™". Сорри, если задел

Comment: Конечно, к мнению что "качественных вопросов очень мало" стоит относиться как к субъективному - я просматриваю всего несколько меток, а не весь ruSO (думаю, как и многие тут); к тому же, у каждого свой личный взгляд на оценку качества.

Comment: Я ставлю вопросу +, если хочу привлечь к нему внимание потенциальных отвечающих, а минус -- только если это явный бред и не стоит тратить время на его чтение